# Adobe's Packager for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, air, flex4

Can Adobe's Packager for iPhone be used for building applications from Flash Builder for Adobe AIR apps? Or is it that only Flash CS5 can be used for iphone apps? I want to deploy AIR apps built for the PC to ipad/iphone. Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a feature of Adobe Flash CS5.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/

Comment: so i can't use the free AIR sdk either?

Comment: No. It does not look like it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since CS5 simply uses a command line tool called PFI. Below is a blog post with details on how to get it setup. This is up-to-date since the re-release of the packager. Now this does require you to own CS5 but there is no reason Adobe in the future could not release it separate and I would be surprised if it wasn't made free soon.

http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ant task into Flash Builder to manual compile you ipa using the instruction provided by Greg